# SQL Server Express 2008 Merge Replication using RMO causes "An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch." error?

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-2.0

I am trying to create a Merge Replication using RMO Programming which i got from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146941%28SQL.105%29.aspx)!

```
        string publisherName = "DataSourceName";
        string publicationName = "AdvWorksSalesOrdersMerge";
        string publicationDbName = "AdventureWorksDW2008R2";
        ReplicationDatabase publicationDb;
        MergePublication publication;
        // Create a connection to the Publisher.
        ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection(publisherName);
          try
        {
             //Connect to the Publisher.
            conn.Connect();

            // Enable the database for merge publication.               
            publicationDb = new ReplicationDatabase(publicationDbName, conn);
            if (publicationDb.LoadProperties())
            {
                if (!publicationDb.EnabledMergePublishing)
                {
                    publicationDb.EnabledMergePublishing = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
               //  Do something here if the database does not exist. 
                throw new ApplicationException(String.Format(
                    "The {0} database does not exist on {1}.",
                    publicationDb, publisherName));
            }

            // Set the required properties for the merge publication.
            publication = new MergePublication();
            publication.ConnectionContext = conn;
            publication.Name = publicationName;
            publication.DatabaseName = publicationDbName;

            // Enable precomputed partitions.
            publication.PartitionGroupsOption = PartitionGroupsOption.True;

             //Specify the Windows account under which the Snapshot Agent job runs.
            // This account will be used for the local connection to the 
            // Distributor and all agent connections that use Windows Authentication.

              publication.SnapshotGenerationAgentProcessSecurity.Login = userid;
               publication.SnapshotGenerationAgentProcessSecurity.Password = password;

             //Explicitly set the security mode for the Publisher connection
            // Windows Authentication (the default).
            publication.SnapshotGenerationAgentPublisherSecurity.WindowsAuthentication = true;

             //Enable Subscribers to request snapshot generation and filtering.
            publication.Attributes |= PublicationAttributes.AllowSubscriberInitiatedSnapshot;
            publication.Attributes |= PublicationAttributes.DynamicFilters;

            // Enable pull and push subscriptions.
            publication.Attributes |= PublicationAttributes.AllowPull;
            publication.Attributes |= PublicationAttributes.AllowPush;

            if (!publication.IsExistingObject)
            {
                 //Create the merge publication.
                publication.Create();

                // Create a Snapshot Agent job for the publication.
                publication.CreateSnapshotAgent();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(String.Format(
                    "The {0} publication already exists.", publicationName));
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             //Implement custom application error handling here.
            throw new Exception(String.Format("The publication {0} could not be created.", publicationName), ex);

        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Disconnect();
        }
```

but at this line 

**publicationDb.EnabledTransPublishing = true;**
i am getting error -" ***An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.***"
So please help me out from this problem ..
waiting for your answers..

Answer (score 0):

You Probably have you answer by now but for those who might be asking the same question.  Its because you are using an express version of SQL Server and Publisher/distributors cannot be created in any version of SQl Server Express.

The instance you have in your code there is not a valid instance hence the exception is thrown.

take a look at:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151819(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151819%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

and the lines that say

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express can serve as a Subscriber for all types of replication, providing a convenient way to distribute data to client applications that use this edition of SQL Server. When using SQL Server Express in a replication topology, keep the following considerations in mind:
>   SQL Server Express cannot serve as a Publisher or Distributor. However, merge replication allows changes to be replicated in both directions between a Publisher and Subscriber.
>   Blockquote